# how to collect spark dataframe as map using col name as key, col val as value

Tags: apache-spark

I am looking for a neat approach to find max value of each column and collect in a map as `{col name:max value of col}`. Here is how far I get so far in a toy example. In my full data there are hundreds columns, so manual casting each columns is not an option ..

```
scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala>

scala> val df = Seq((1,3), (4, 1), (2, 2)).toDF("a", "b")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int]

scala> val df1 = df.groupBy().max()

scala> df1.show
+------+------+
|max(a)|max(b)|
+------+------+
|     4|     3|
+------+------+

### goal ### 
{a:4,b:3}


``
```

Comment: what spark version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may collect your max values and zip with column names to get your tuple2(colname, maxVal)

`toSeq` on `Row` preserves the order

```
scala> df.show
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
|  4|  1|
|  2|  2|
+---+---+


scala> df.groupBy().max().show
+------+------+
|max(a)|max(b)|
+------+------+
|     4|     3|
+------+------+


scala> df.groupBy().max().collect.head
res63: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [4,3]

scala> df.columns zip df.groupBy().max().collect.head.toSeq
res64: Array[(String, Any)] = Array((a,4), (b,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see below solution , is this what are you trying to achieve.
Code is written in python. Please convert it to as per yours

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = sc.parallelize([(1,3), (4, 1), (2, 2)]).toDF(["a", "b"])

df1=df.select(max(col('a')).alias('a'),max(col('b')).alias('b'))

r={}
for i in df1.columns:
  r[i]=df1.select(i).collect()[0][0]
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` to compare each group of numbers, and take the max between them at each index:

```scala
val ds: Dataset[Seq[Int]] =
  Seq(Seq(1,3), Seq(4, 1), Seq(2, 2)).toDS()

val maxes: Seq[Int] =
  ds.reduce { (xs, ys) =>
    xs.zip(ys).map { case (x, y) =>
      Seq(x, y).max
    }
  }

println(maxes) // (4, 3)
```

Comment: is it possible doing it directly on dataframe, instead of convert it to dataset first? As my dataframe have over hundred columns

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|1  |3  |
|4  |1  |
|2  |2  |
+---+---+


scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

df
 .groupBy()
 .agg(max("a").as("a"),max("b").as("b"))
 .select(
     map(
         lit("a"),$"a",
         lit("b"),$"b"
        ).as("mp")
    )
 .map(_.getMap[String,Int](0)).collect
 .flatten
 .toMap


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res45: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 4, b -> 3)
```